# select function not working in 3.5.4 version of d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have updated d3.js from 3.5.3 to 3.5.4. 
I am getting below error since last update. The code code works on 3.5.3 version though.

```
D:\softwares\nodejs\node_modules\d3\d3.js:562
    return n.querySelector(s);
         ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'querySelector' of undefined
    at d3_select (D:\softwares\nodejs\node_modules\d3\d3.js:562:14)
    at Object.d3.select (D:\softwares\nodejs\node_modules\d3\d3.js:1043:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous
(D:\softwares\nodejs\node_modules\chart.js:63:14)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:943:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

This is my line of code where I am getting error?
Do I need to add anything more for using 3.5.4 version?

```
var svg = d3.select('body').html('').append('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
    .attr('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr('id', 'app-d3-bar-chart')
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
```

Comment: Given that you seem to be running this on node, the following from the [release notes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/releases) comes to mind: "Zero dependencies! JSDOM is now limited to a development dependency for testing".

Comment: Does it means that JSDOM needs to be added a required dependency if you are using d3js on node ?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff  I am not clear what it exactly means. Could you please explain it? I am using d3 on node server.

Comment: Yes, I would try to include JSDOM.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: PS - jsdom no long works with Node.js.

Answer (score 3):

As of [d3#3.5.4](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/releases/tag/v3.5.4), JSDOM is a development dependency. You will need to include it as a dependency. Be mindful that JSDOM 4.0.0 requires io.js, use 3.x for Node.js. For me dependencies that work are:

```
"dependencies": {
  "d3": "~3.5.5",
  "jsdom": "~3.1.2"
}
```

Then in your code replace line:

```
var svg = d3.select('body').html('').append('svg')
```

with

```
var document = require('jsdom').jsdom();
var svg = d3.select(document.body).html('').append('svg')
```

Refer to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/andredumas/ad585d6d68cf8a894207#file-index-js) for a working example.