# d3.js undefined in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, meteor

I am an experienced Meteor developer, as well as experienced with d3...but I cant get them to work together!

I have tried:

`meteor add d3js:d3`, which crashes and produces:

> d3 is not defined

`<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` crashes and produces:

> d3 is not defined

`<script src="d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`, with the source in the top level of my project directory, which crashes and produces:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'querySelector' of undefined

(the previous two both in the header of my `index.html` file)

all the while, d3 is still undefined in my browser.

Ive updated all of my packages and Meteor, as well as disabled every Meteor package, other than d3js:d3.

Looking for a solution (to my potential idiocy) or a work around.

**EDIT**

Adding:
`pete:jsdom` produces new error message:

> /Users/Admin/.meteor/packages/pete_jsdom/.0.0.2.1uo6lix++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:3
>   `jsdom 4.x onward only works on io.js or Node.js 4 or newer: https://github.co

Comment: what do you mean by the first `crashes and produces`? when does that happen? already when you run the `meteor add` or only when you start the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you have a bug elsewhere. The following works perfectly fine on my machine (osx):

```
meteor create d3
cd d3
meteor add d3js:d3
meteor
```

Then, opening the browser I can do in the console:

```
> typeof(d3)
"object"

> _.keys(d3)
["version", "ascending", "descending", "min", "max", "extent", "sum", "mean", "quantile", "median", "variance", "deviation", "bisectLeft", "bisectRight", "bisect", "bisector", "shuffle", "permute", "pairs", "zip", "transpose", "keys", "values", "entries", "merge", "range", "map", "nest", "set", "behavior", "rebind", "dispatch", "event", "requote", "selection", "ns", "select", "selectAll", "mouse", "touch", "touches", "interpolateZoom", "color", "hsl", "hcl", "lab", "rgb", "functor", "xhr", "dsv", "csv", "tsv", "timer", "round", "formatPrefix", "time", "locale", "format", "geo", "geom", "interpolateRgb", "interpolateObject", "interpolateNumber", "interpolateString", "interpolate", "interpolators", "interpolateArray", "ease", "interpolateHcl", "interpolateHsl", "interpolateLab", "interpolateRound", "transform", "interpolateTransform", "layout", "random", "scale", "svg", "transition", "text", "json", "html", "xml"]
```

Comment: Im getting 
```typeof(d3)
"undefined"```

Comment: so weird...i spun up a new meteor instance and d3 loads fine.  guess ill port my stuff over.  thanks @christian

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you already included this, but [try adding JSDOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30350630/1146881).

> As of d3#3.5.4, JSDOM is a development dependency. You will need to include it as a dependency.

Comment: check updated posted...not sure it's the correct approach

Comment: @redress Hm, any reason why you can't upgrade to the latest version of Node? 4.0 or 5.0 will do.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you only reference d3 on the client. It is not available serverside, thus using it serverside will crash the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
meteor npm install d3
```

instead of

```
meteor add d3js:d3
```

It works for me

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question.

Comment: I am not very sure that my answer is as same as any answer here. My suggestion is using d3 npm package instead of meteor package.